# postgres=# du and shows all files

Tags: postgresql

I was playing around with PostgreSQL 11 and I entered `postgres=# du` in my terminal without connecting to my server first. All of my files on my computer were listed next to a number. I'm wondering if this changed anything on my computer? When I connect to my server and type `du`, I get the listed users on the server. I just want to make sure I didn't change anything by entering  `postgres=# du` in my terminal without connecting to my server first. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to show Postgres users use command [\du](https://tomcam.github.io/postgres/#du-display-user-roles) after connecting via psql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fine.  the "du" command in *nix means "disk usage" and you just got a list of how much disk all your files are using.

for more information

```
 $ man du
```